# Environment problem when administering macos with saltstack tools

Tags: macos, salt-stack, system-administration

I have a few dozen mac computers on which I have a task to install various software (putty, git, draw-io, mosquitto), as well as to curtail the user's permissions (e.g. so that the user cannot download software himself). I manually installed saltstack on each of these computers, then ran salt master and accepted all keys. I then wrote some .sls files to install po, however I get an error every time:

```
     ID: homebrew
        Function: pkg.installed
          Result: False
         Comment: Unable to run command '['brew', '--prefix']' with the context '{'cwd': '/var/root', 'shell': False, 'env': {'OLDPWD': '/', 'PATH':
 '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'PWD': '/opt/salt', 'XPC_FLAGS': '0x0',
 'XPC_SERVICE_NAME': '0', 'SHLVL': '0', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C', 'SSL_CERT_DIR':
 '/private/etc/ssl/certs', 'SSL_CERT_FILE': '/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem',
 'LC_NUMERIC': 'C', 'LC_TIME': 'C', 'LC_COLLATE': 'C', 'LC_MONETARY': 'C',
 'LC_MESSAGES': 'C', 'LC_PAPER': 'C', 'LC_NAME': 'C', 'LC_ADDRESS': 'C',
 'LC_TELEPHONE': 'C', 'LC_MEASUREMENT': 'C', 'LC_IDENTIFICATION': 'C',
 'LANGUAGE': 'C'}, 'stdin': None, 'stdout': -1, 'stderr': -2, 
'with_communicate': True, 'timeout': None, 'bg': False, 'close_fds': True}',
 reason: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'brew'
         Started: 17:51:13.166312
        Duration: 15.798 ms
         Changes:
    
              ID: putty
        Function: pkg.installed
          Result: False
         Comment: One or more requisite failed: mac.software.putty.homebrew
         Started: 17:51:13.182820
        Duration: 0.003 ms
         Changes:
    -----------
    Summary for MAC-08-mac.local
```

I have tried many options to fix the error. I downloaded brew as a separate file and tried to install it before I installed putty. I also tried changing the sudo_user variable in /etc/salt/minion, as well as just user, because I thought the error was in brew from root. Also tried the brew extension "Homebrew Cask", but the error is always the same. I found a thread on the narkive.com forum, where they said that the HOME environment variable is to blame. Actually, I stopped searching for it because I ran out of resources. So I would like to know from professional sysadmins or more knowledgeable people what is the matter and how to fix it (don't judge me harshly, I am a first time system administrator and I am just learning). Just in case I will attach the command I use to run the script:

salt 'MAC-08-mac.local' state.highstate saltenv=development

I am rooting myself (I tried rootless with sudo, but nothing changed). I run the script from the directory
/opt/salt/development/mac/software. in software there are scripts such as putty.sls, visual-studio-code.sls.... And the file software-mac.sls, which is located in /opt/salt/development/mac, is launched. It lists the files that are launched via inclusion (I tried to repeat the architecture from the book "Salt Cookbook" by Aniban Saha). As a possible error variant I will also show putty.sls:

```
putty:
  pkg.installed:
    - require:
      - pkg: homebrew
```

also homebrew.sls:

```
homebrew:
  pkg.installed
```

and /opt/salt/development/mac/software-mac.sls:

```
include:
#soft
  - software.homebrew
  - software.putty
```

I would be extremely grateful for any information on the topic and links to literature that may advance this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

`pkg.installed` uses Homebrew to install things on macOS. Therefore it is not possible to use it to install Homebrew. Hence the error about not being able to find `brew`.

You need to install Homebrew first via some other means (e.g. a `macpackage.installed` or `cmd.run` state) before any `pkg` states will work.

---

Alternatively, if you were expecting Salt to use MacPorts instead of Homebrew, add the following to the minion config:

```yaml
providers:
  pkg: mac_portspkg
```

Similarly, MacPorts would need to be installed first before any `pkg` states are run.

Comment: The problem is that brew is installed natively on each of the administered computers. I personally used it to install various programs, such as python or git, in the macos terminal. It’s strange that when brew salt is installed it doesn’t want to work with it. It feels like the problem is in the environment, but I can't figure it out. I tried to do this:
nginx:
   pkg.installed:
     - name: nginx
   service.running:
     - enable: True
     - reload: True
   watch:
     - service: mac_service
     - pkg: mac_brew_pkg

Comment: It seems to be a bug, which you can probably work around by ensuring `brew` is on the minion's `PATH`.

Comment: But either way, your `homebrew.sls` can never work.

Comment: How do I add brew to minion's PATH? Is this done in /etc/salt/minion? 
In principle, I could try to use .dmg to install programs, but I don’t know how to do this and how to work with the Share folder in Salt

Comment: It depends how the service is managed. Though `ln -s $(which brew) /usr/bin/` should also do it.

Comment: I didn't understand about MacPorts. Should this be put in /etc/salt/minion or on the master? Should I change my .sls files for this? Maybe there is some article or book where you can get acquainted with this in more detail?

Comment: If you don't know what MacPorts is then you are unlikely to be trying to use it.